# Windows Forms Control.CreateControl() equivalent in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, handle

normally I use UserControls from WinForms and can then have them created with the [CreateControl()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.createhandle?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-control-createhandle) method and displayed in another application. But now I wanted to try this with WPF. But there I can't find a way to create the UserControl and then get the corresponding handle.

I tried it with

```
HwndSource hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(Control) as HwndSource;  

if (hwndSource != null)  
{  
    handle = hwndSource.Handle;  
}
```

but i got no handle.

Then there is this possibility, which theoretically works, but only for Windows

```
IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(myWindow).EnsureHandle();
```

Normal Usage with WinForms Controls on a Sample:

```
MyCoolControl control = new MyCoolControl();
control.CreateControl();

SendHandleToSomethingElse(control.Handle.ToInt32());
```

and now i need this for WPF :D

Comment: "Then there is this possibility, which theoretically works, but only for Windows" so where's the problem? WPF only works on Windows as well. And btw, you're talking about `CreateControl` but are linking to the `CreateHandle` method, which one is it?

Comment: I Need this for Controls and not for Windows and if i Create the Control i will get the Handle

Comment: Ahh, for multiple `Window`s, not Windows the OS

Comment: i put a sample how i work in the Question

Comment: The code is correct, but the assumptions are not.  A WPF control does not have a handle by design.  Only a toplevel window does, controls borrow that window's drawing surface to make themselves visible.  Windows UI frameworks have a rich history of "windowless controls", WPF is a lot like VB6 that way.  Intention is to reduce overhead imposed by the OS, there's a ton of appcompat in a HWND.  You have to use a [HwndHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-win32-control-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to get ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike a Windows Forms control, a WPF control doesn't have its own HWND handle.

In WPF only the top-level window has a handle and the controls are rendered as content inside this HWND.

Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-and-win32-interoperation?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) for more information about how WPF uses HWNDs.